# Why keyboard accessibility doesn't work for Bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the Bootstrap dropdown keyboard accessible in my page. But I don't know why keydown/up doesn't work. Please see the my [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/4672z/1/)

And I also have some questions on Bootstrap accessibility. Please help to review it.

1. According the [Issue 931](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/931). It seems the keyboard accessibility wasn't added until v3.0.0-rc1. Right?
2. Why missing `href` in the anchor element would disable keyup/down accessibility for dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the following source code of bootstrap's dropdown.js that is using to find index of focused element:

```
var index = $items.index($items.filter(':focus'))
```

the problem is that the `$items.filter(':focus')` don't returns correct element and in this case index will be `-1` each time.

I don't know how jQuery's `:focus` exactly works but this problem can be solved with the following code: `var index = $items.index($(document.activeElement))`. But anywhere it's not good thing to change something in source code of 3rd-party library.

Comment: no, -1 means no item in the list is focus. so in that case the expected behavior is focus on the first item when keyup/down. I don't think it is a bug.

Comment: @Joe.wang, I just explained why keyboard accessibility doesn't work (i.e. only the first item in dropdown is selected) when `href` tag is missing.

Comment: @Joe.wang, and yes when it's is -1 then it selects 1st item in list. But it happens each time on keydown/up

Comment: So, if it is like what you said, It supposed to select 1st all the time. But actually none of them is selected .

Comment: So `-1` is not the reason .

Comment: @Joe.wang, what browser you are using? I tested it in Opera,Chrome, IE11 and Firefox and in all of them it selects the 1st after pressing keydown **[image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kfnw3h9tqczyx0/2014-07-31%2009_40_42-Test%20bootstrap-angular%20accessibility%20-%20JSFiddle%C2%A0%E2%80%94%20Opera.png)**

Comment: Sorry I said before `actually none of them is selected` is wrong. It always select first one item.